# Where is the location of Developers Tool (edge) in file explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, developer-tools

I was curious where the Developers Tool from Microsoft edge was. Because I wanted to see how many code there was written for the DevTool.

Comment: I don't understand, are you looking for an executable file?

Comment: That isn't necessary. I just want to know the folder of all the files from the Developers Tool from edge.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are not that clear.

You may find the executable in:

```
 C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-e..crosoftedgedevtools_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_65a5646e8443d0f8\MicrosoftEdgeDevTools.exe
```

But from its small size, 95 KB, it doesn't seem that this is more than
just a front-end.
As Microsoft Edge is closed-source, this is all a black hole.

You could instead examine the sources of Chromium, of which Microsoft Edge
is derived. The sources of the Dev Tools are found in
[ChromeDevTools / devtools-frontend](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend).